# How to use percent_of_equity in double takeprofit strategy

Tags: pine-script, trading, tradingview-api

This code has two take profit levels. One at 1 atr where 50% of the trade is closed, and after that, a TrailingStop will close the remains of the trade.

My question:
The code recognizes which take profit to use by the position size.
If the position size is the full, initial position size it should close 50% of the trade.
But how can I identify the initial position size of lets say 2% of total equity?
Please see the ***((( What should go here for "Full size of trade"?)))*** in the code below.
Or am I doing this in a stupid way? It worked well with a fixed number of contracts.

Thank you!

```
strategy('Trail', overlay=true, currency=currency.USD,default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=2)

if strategy.position_size > 0 and high > long_tp
long_sl := TrailingStop
long_sl

if strategy.position_size < 0 and low < short_tp
short_sl := TrailingStop
short_sl

if strategy.position_size == 0
strategy.entry('buy', strategy.long, when=Buy)

if strategy.position_size == ***((( What should go here for "Full size of trade"?)))***
strategy.exit('buyExit1', stop=long_sl, qty_percent=50, limit=long_tp)

if strategy.position_size > 0
strategy.exit('buyExit2', qty_percent=100, stop=long_sl)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `strategy.opentrades.size(strategy.opentrades-1)` will return you the size of contracts in the last opened trade (existing position size).
2. Get rid of `if` expressions. Those exits will wait for the `limit` and `stop` to be filled and exit 50% of the initial position:

```
strategy.exit('buyExit1', stop=long_sl, qty_percent=50, limit=long_tp)
strategy.exit('buyExit2', qty_percent=50, stop=long_sl)
```

so both exits will close 100% of the position anyway.